# For whom or with whom

Tags: word-choice

I sometimes mix up between for whom and with whom

Could anyone please help me when to use for whom and with whom

In this sentence

My role model is my father, from/with whom I have become a better person.

Comment: Yes , if possible. I hope you can clear my confusion

Comment: [***...through** whom I have*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=through+whom+I+have+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) *become a better person.* Neither ***from*** nor ***with*** are suitable for this context.

Comment: Thank you, sir Can you help me on how can I use (for whom or with whom) is it after preposition or without them and how . Thank you again.

Comment: "My father, for whom I had bought a present..." (I had bought it **for him**.) "My father, with whom I went to the theatre last night..." (I went **with him**.)

Comment: Thank you @KateBunting  why don't you use simple past. like ( my father, for whom I bought a present on his 60th birthday.)

Comment: No particular reason, except that your sentence used the perfect tense! The tense isn't relevant to the choice of  preposition.

Comment: who has made me become a better person,

Answer (score 0):

> My role model is my father, **from/with/for** whom I have become a better person.

With *for*, the clause means you've become a better person for his sake, which does not go quite well with the preceding clause.

*from* and *with* can't work here.  To use them, we need to elaborate the sentences to, for example

> ... from whom I have **learned to** become a better person.

> ... with whom I have **spent much time in order to** become a better person.

The neatest would be

> ... **through** whom I have become a better person.

as what @FumbleFingers suggested.